# Variable (List) not persisting when making two requests - FLASK

Tags: python, list, rest, flask, routes

I´m having problems building a Flask application. I have a module called 'routes.py' where I have all my routes written. And then I have another module called 'functions.py' where I have some functions related to the routes. The thing is, that when I make an specific request to one route, I want to append some data to a list, all this being saved in the 'functions.py' module, which is called in every route. So the problem is, that every time I make a request, the list resets to 0 and its empty. How can I persist that list? I´ve tried creating a list in another module and persisting it but hasn´t worked. I let you here a schema with the problem. Thanks!

**routes.py**

```
@bp.route('/a_route', methods=['POST'])
def a_route():
    try:

        dict={
                "some_data": "some_data"
        }

        p = Process(target=a_function, args=(dict,))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()

    except Exception as err:
        return make_response(jsonify({
            "err": True
        }), 500)
    else:
        return make_response(jsonify({
            "err": False
        }), 200)
```

The above function calls 'a_function' that is in functions.py.

**functions.py**

```
#receives some data
# and appends that data to a list (this list is empty every time I call a function, that´s de problem
list.append(dict['some_data']
```

Answer (score 0):

put dict initiation out of a_route function should solve this problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That dict is just a way to pass parameters to the function. The list that is being lost is the one that is used in 'functions', and that list is initiated outside every function.